# Send NSArray & Struct in NSData through Game Centre

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, game-center, multiplayer

I am creating a game that sends some data between devices in multiplayer game centre.

The data I'm sending includes an NSArray & a message to notify the other player of a change in the score.

I have defined the struct for the score message as such:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MessageType) {
    kMessageTypeUpdateScore
};

typedef struct {
    MessageType messageType;
} Message;

typedef struct {
    Message message;
    int score;
} MessageUpdateScore;
```

And here's the code for receiving the data:

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID {

    NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    // data is an array

    Message *message = (Message *)[data bytes];
    if (message->messageType == kMessageTypeUpdateScore) {
        // data is a message
    }

}
```

My question is - how do I differentiate between the NSArray & Message such that I can unpack the NSData and do different things with it accordingly?

Comment: Add a *sentinel* byte in the first element of the `NSData` which defines the content.

Comment: How can this be done? Is it similar to appending a byte to some mutable data?

Comment: Similar, yes, but you put it at the front.

Comment: I've tried doing that, but I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I try to read it back. Could you outline the steps or code for inserting & reading the byte?

Comment: Well firstly is there no way to create a single data structure that is capable of holding whatever is in the `NSArray` and the score so there is only ever one type of message being sent?

Comment: If you're asking whether the content of the array and the score can be merged into a single data structure, then probably not. One, because the score is being sent more frequently than the array and two, because that would create issues in the game when I try to read the array.

Comment: You want to encode/decode the two items into/from a byte stream.  Why not use the NSCoder routines to pack it up and instead of writing a file, send the data as a message, and unpack it at the receiving end?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, you can find my solution here:
[How to Covert struct with an Array of string to NSData and vice versa Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564314/how-to-covert-struct-with-an-array-of-string-to-nsdata-and-vice-versa-swift/31586644#31586644)

if you have found some better solutions please leave some feedback.

You can find a working example [here](https://github.com/MarcoMig/Swift-struct-to-NSData).